# How to make a payable transferFrom function that inherits from openzeppelin erc721 contract

Tags: solidity, ethereumj

I have just finished the crypto zombies tutorial https://cryptozombies.io/ and wanted to get it working locally but also using a solc 0.8.0. Compilation has thrown me lots of errors, many of which I just had to change external to public in my overrides and also add the override modifier. There is one issue, however, that I am unsure how to resolve. The contract inherits from the @openzeppelin/contracts version of ERC721. The two functions I am having issues with use the payable modifier.

```
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public payable override {
    require (zombieToOwner[_tokenId] == msg.sender || zombieApprovals[_tokenId] == msg.sender);
    _transfer(_from, _to, _tokenId);
  }

  function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId) public payable override onlyOwnerOf(_tokenId) {
    zombieApprovals[_tokenId] = _approved;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _approved, _tokenId);
  }
```

I get an error during compilation..

```
TypeError: Overriding function changes state mutability from "nonpayable" to "payable".
```

So I find that in the ERC721 contract, neither of these functions is marked as payable.

So my question is do I remove the payable modifiers in my function overrides? I thought that this would mean the function/tx cannot carry an ether value. Or do I add the modifiers to the functions in the contracts I am inheriting from? Why do the functions lack these modifiers if (from what I have read) solidity expects them to be present in these two functions? Or am I missing something? I am unsure how to proceed so any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use *payable* when you're explicitly sending WETH. Sending tokens or NFTs does not inheritably cost WETH (only gas). If the transfer function calls another function it will inherit *payable* from the called function.

Comment: holy moses you're right. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I also have this exact problem. The thing is to be able to integrate royalty I first thought to make the transferFrom function payable but that was not possible.. Then I discovered ERC2981 Contract (royalty protocol).. However I can't get it working.. I mean I minted on my project and then tried to sell it on Opensea but there was no royalty payment.I will post a link here. I hope you can get it working. If you can get it working can you please give feedback about this royalty...
The link is : https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981

Comment: Royalty is not enforced by opensea yet.